# How do I create a table migration for Foo has and belongs to many Foos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have a Person model and a Person can have multiple children but also has multiple parents.

Creating a join table with `rails generate migration CreateJoinTablePersonPerson person person`, would give me this:

```
class CreateJoinTablePersonPerson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :people, :people do |t|
      # t.index [:person_id, :person_id]
      # t.index [:person_id, :person_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Running the above migration obviously results in: `CREATE TABLE "people_people" ("person_id" integer NOT NULL);`.

How do I create a table migration for a table that has and belongs to many itselves? Should I even be using habtm, or should I be using some sort of "has many through" construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want self assosiation with many to many relation.

Please create a seperate model name: parent_child, in which you have two foreign keys.

1) parent_id

2) child_id

So for each relation, eg: for new entry for parent, child_id is self.id while parent_id is of parent and for child relation, parent_id: self.id while child_id is of child.

you should add migration.

```
 rails g model parent_child
```

this will result in migration, add column parent_id and child_id to it.

```
  class CreateTableParentChildren < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
          create_table :parent_children do |t|
            t.integer :parent_id
            t.integer :child_id
          end
         #add indexes on both
      end
  end
```

now in parent class. you should add something like this.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :children, class_name: "ParentChild", foreign_key: "parent_id"
   has_many :parents,  class_name: "ParentChild", foreign_key: "child_id" 
end
```

I hope this idea will help you implement what you want.